# Profile pictures not visible in web parts

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

Since a couple of weeks the profile pictures of users are (suddenly) not visible anymore in the contacts web parts of SharePoint online. It is unknown to me what caused this and how to debug it.

The service health page of SharePoint Online doesn't show any errors and the search center seems to correctly crawled the PublishingImage, PictureURL and PictureThumbnailURL properties.

[image: profile pictures]

What is the best place to look for possible errors besides the search center and the user profile page in the Sharepoint Admin Center?

Comment: Per my test, profile pictures of users are visible anymore in the contacts details web parts of SharePoint online.
I need to collect the following information to further troubleshoot the issue: Does Profile picture displayed in Office 365 Suite Bar? Does Profile picture displayed in Office Delve? Does Profile picture displayed in Outlook on the Web?

Comment: @LisaChenMSFT It works in the Office 365 Suite Bar, Delve, Outlook and all other online apps.